# How to change cellspacing of a table in latex?

Tags: tables

I've tried searching the answer here, but I did not find it. I have a plenty of 25x25 table with long entries. The table should fit in an A4 sheet of paper. I tried using "landscape". It helped a bit, but there are some tables which still don't fit.

Can anyone tell me how can I change cellspacing of the table, that is the distance between borders of its elements?

Comment: \setlength\tabcolsep{2in}

Comment: and for vertical spacing, `\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used the vertical lines on purpose here, to show their effect on spacing.

Following example shows the influence of `\tabcolsep` as spacing between borders,the black color box demonstrates the typing area compared to the spacing to the left and right.

Normally, `\tabcolsep` defaults to `6pt`.

If vertical lines are also included, there is an additional `\arrayrulewidth`, defaulting to `0.4pt`, changing this affects the thickness of the horizontal rules created by `\hline`.

This all holds for standard `tabular` environment, without adding extra `table` packages.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}



\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{24}{l|}}
\hline
\colorbox{black}{\parbox{1cm}{\hspace{1cm}}} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \tabularnewline
\hline
\colorbox{black}{\parbox{1cm}{\hspace{1cm}}} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Normal tabcolsep length: \the\tabcolsep, normal vertical spacing of \arraystretch}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{24}{l|}}
\hline
\colorbox{black}{\parbox{1cm}{\hspace{1cm}}} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Changed tabcolsep length: \the\tabcolsep} 
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.0pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{24}{l|}}
\hline
\colorbox{black}{\parbox{1cm}{\hspace{1cm}}} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Changed tabcolsep length: \the\tabcolsep}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}%
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{24}{l|}}
\hline
\colorbox{black}{\parbox{1cm}{\hspace{1cm}}} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Normal tabcolsep length: \the\tabcolsep, changed arrayrulewidth to \the\arrayrulewidth}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{24}{l|}}
\hline
\colorbox{black}{\parbox{1cm}{\hspace{1cm}}} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \tabularnewline
\hline
\colorbox{black}{\parbox{1cm}{\hspace{1cm}}} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Normal tabcolsep length: \the\tabcolsep, reduced verticalspacing to \arraystretch}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]