# Reducing space between columns manually

Tags: tables, spacing

I'm working on a table in `report` documentclass. Here's some of my code below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 


\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l p{6cm} c m{3cm} r m{3cm}  }
\hline \\ 
 Country &   Parameter A & Parameter B  \\ [0.5ex]
\hline 

Quantity of x  &    0.8   & 25.6  \\ 

Quantity of y  &    100   & 9.4   \\  

Quantity of z  &    10    & 12.6   \\ 

Quantity of a  &  100   & 30    \\ 




\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table 1}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

My problem is that columns 2 and 3 are too wide apart. How can I get them to be a little closer together whilst giving more space to column 1 as I have more writing to do in column 1? I've read quite a lot of answers online and on this forum but I guess I'm missing something very fundamental here. I've played around a lot with `\begin{tabular}{l p{6cm} c m{3cm} r m{3cm}  }` but all to no avail.

Comment: Welcome, do you mind updating your example code such that it compiles (makes it easier for others to work with, and makes it more likely to get help). You example is e.g. missing `\begin/end{docuyment}`

Comment: Why do you declare 6 columns and use 3?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183264/how-to-change-cellspacing-of-a-table-in-latex and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195899/unwanted-padding-in-tabular-columns-when-cells-contain-multiple-rows

Comment: @Bernard-could you be more specific-I'm guessing this is probably where the problem is. Do you mean I should be writing something like \begin{tabular}{ p{6cm}  p{3cm} p{3cm}  }?

Comment: @John: I think, that was what Bernard meant. And did you consider the `\tabcolsep` length between the columns?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer, Ive now added the `\tabcolsep` command and its now working. I think the problem was that I specified 6 columns instead of the intended 3. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, you have declared too many columns in your table. I deleted three of them. If you want to write long text in one column, you may use a `p{width}` column in order to control it to your needs.

Here is your table how I would recommend to type it:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype} % for better kerning in narrow columns
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}S[table-format=3.1]S[table-format=2.1]} % adapt this 3cm to your needs
            \toprule 
            Country         & {Parameter A} & {Parameter B} \\
            \midrule            
            Quantity of $x$ & 0.8           & 25.6          \\          
            Quantity of $y$ & 100           & 9.4           \\              
            Quantity of $z$ & 10            & 12.6          \\                      
            Quantity of $a$ and some more writing if you like & 100 & 30 \\             
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Table 1}       
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

I included the package `microtype` here in order to get a better kerning in narrow cells with long text. If you are having that much space, you could just adapt the width of the first column until it looks nice to you. If you are getting ugly results like in my screenshot or if you want all the "Quantity of..." aligned horizontally, you should make the last cell (or the first row) ragged right (thanks to Barbara Beeton for this objection).

This could look like `\multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedright}p{3cm}}{Quantity of $a$ and some more writing if you like}`, which yields:

[image]

Comment: I had the same idea. Finally, the second column would look better if simply centred, in my opinion.

Comment: @Bernard Yes you are right for the single case, but maybe those were just dummy numbers. Don't know. I like to keep it consistent. At John: You may want to write `100.0` if you think that too dismembered or you omit all the `siunitx` beauty I am advocating here.

Comment: the last entry in column 1 would really look better ragged right.

Comment: @barbarabeeton sure. Will add that. Thanks.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, thanks so much for your answer. The numbers were just dummy numbers.

Comment: @John Glad I could help. When you insert your real numbers, just adapt the `[table-format=sx.y]` (`s`: sign if any, `x`: number of digits before, and `y`: number of digits after the dot) and write possible text cells in curly braces (like I did in the header row).

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, could you specify which part of your code do I put `\multicolumn{1}{>{\raggedright}p{3cm}}{Quantity of $a$ and some more writing if you like}` ?

Comment: @John The first cell in the last row has to be replaced by this. Just remove the text and put my command.